# What is the proper way to optionally compile a library with a build flag (to place in `target_compatible_with`)?

Tags: c++, build, bazel, bazel-rules

Suppose I have a library implementation that I only want to compile when the user specifies it at build time.

Should I use the `features` flag?

If so, how could I use the features flag to constrain compilation like you can with `target_compatible_with` in `cc_library`, `cc_test`, and `cc_binary`?

If not, what is the best way to constrain this? Adjusting the `platforms` flag disturbs default platform detection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [user-defined build setting](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/config.html#user-defined-build-settings) that is a command-line flag. The easiest way is to use one of the [common build settings rules](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/main/rules/common_settings.bzl), and instantiate it in a BUILD file (call it `flags/BUILD` for this example):

```py
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:common_settings.bzl", "bool_flag")
bool_flag(
    name = "flag",
    build_setting_default = False,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Then you can set it [from the command line](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/config.html#using-build-settings-on-the-command-line) with `--//flags:flag`. If you want a less ugly syntax, [build setting aliases](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/config.html#using-build-setting-aliases) are also available.

Once you have something which can trigger a [config_setting](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/general.html#config_setting), making an optional library is pretty straightforwards. First you want to disable the library itself when the flag isn't set:

```py
config_setting(
    name = "have_flag",
    flag_values = {
        "//flags:flag": "true",
    },
)

cc_library(
    name = "sometimes",
    target_compatible_with = select({
        ":have_flag": [],
        "//conditions:default": ["@platforms//:incompatible"],
    }),
)
```

Anything marked as requiring `@platforms//:incompatible` will never be compatible with any real platform, so this will skip the library when you `bazel build //...` without the flag and make it an error for anything to depend on it.

I'm guessing you have other targets that depend on this library when enabled, which can be handled similarly:

```py
cc_binary(
    name = "thing",
    deps = [
        "//:something_else",
    ] + select({
        ":have_flag": [":sometimes"],
        "//conditions:default": [],
    }),
)
```

If you want to define a preprocessor macro to tell the dependent code whether to use the optional dependency (or swap out source files, or change link options, etc), then you can use `select` like that for `copts`, `defines`, `srcs`, and most of the other `cc_library`/`cc_binary` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the tag `manual`, e.g.:

```
cc_test(name = "my_test"
        ...
        tags = ["manual"]
)
```